# how to enable OTP verification along with oauth2 flow

Tags: oauth-2.0, one-time-password, multi-factor-authentication

I need to enable two step verification for my users login, currently I am having only password based login. Below is the APIs I am planning add for 2 steps verification

1- User login APIs

```
POST /oauth/login 
Content-Type: application/json
{
     grant_type: 'password',
     username: 'USERNAME',
     password: 'PASSWORD',
     audience: 'API_IDENTIFIER',
     scope: 'SCOPE',
     client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
     client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
}
```

2- Response I am planning from my server if that user needs OTP based authentication also(Server backend sends a OTP to mobile).

```
HTTP/1.1 403 Forbidden
Content-Type: application/json
{
  "error": "otp_required",
  "error_description": "Multi-factor authentication required",
  "otp_token": "eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciD3QCiQ",
  "otpidentifier":"7789346789"  // this is where otp is sent
}
```

3. User Triggers this API after afte they get the OTP along with temporary token sent.

```
POST /outh/otp/verify 
Content-Type: application/json
Authorizatuin:{otp_token} // eyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCJhbGciD3QCiQ
{
     grant_type: 'otp',
     otp: '123456',
     client_id: 'YOUR_CLIENT_ID',
     client_secret: 'YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET'
}
```

4.Final response my Server with proper oauth access token.

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/json
Cache-Control: no-store
Pragma: no-cache

{
  "access_token":"MTQ0NjJkZmQ5OTM2NDE1ZTZjNGZmZjI3",
  "token_type":"bearer",
  "expires_in":3600,
  "refresh_token":"IwOGYzYTlmM2YxOTQ5MGE3YmNmMDFkNTVk",
  "scope":"create"
}
```

Is this the right method or is there a other better or some simple steps exists ?

Comment: Are you implementing your own OAuth2 server? Why don't you send the OTP right in the first auth request along with a password?

Comment: Yes, but I want to send otp only if passowrd  is correct..

Comment: I don't think that's a good approach - you will tell an attacker that the user exists and the password he guessed is correct.

Comment: But when I see most of the other services after login success they ask for otp .. like google after login they ask for any MFA method..

Comment: Do you need to use resource owner password grant?

Comment: Yes.. my authorization service only will provide

Comment: any help on deciding this.

Comment: I don't know, I think your concept is wrong - I would either require both password and OTP right away or I would implement a different flow which would allow the server to present its own GUI with forms for username, password and OTP.

Comment: @scoder how did you end up doing the implementation?